# Change Package Name Bower

Tags: bower

Is it possible to change the name of a bower package after you register it?

I have created a package and pushed up, but I have made a typo.

Can I change this information in a later version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way for package publishers to interact with the Bower registry, that includes unregister / rename. You can make a request for a manual edit here:
https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/120

However this will be available in the future once registry rewrite is done:
https://github.com/bower/registry/issues/73